# if a Label which has been positioned using.place() can be binded in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to python coding and I'm trying to develop a code for my university project. I had hit a dead-end can a label which had been positioned using .Place() be binded with another function?

```
def fun_entry(e):
    status_label.config(text="Severity is a ranking number associated with the most serious effect for a given failure mode.                    ",font=('helvetica',12), background= '#a80f56', foreground='white')

def fun_exit(e):
    status_label.config(text="",background= '#f0f0f0')


i4 = Label(input_frame, text="Function:")#.place(x=6, y=180)(when places cannot be binded)
i4.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
i4.bind("<Enter>", fun_entry)
i4.bind("<Leave>", fun_exit)
ie4 = Entry(input_frame, width=50)#.place(x=150, y=180)
ie4.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
```

I'm trying to bring a hovering text in a status bar and at the same time, I would like to place the label in a particular position. I used a .grid() but it didn't solve my requirement. Is there a possible solution for using .Place() and bind it?

Comment: Binding events on a widget does not depend on what layout function it uses.  And it is easy to test it, just use `.place()` and test.

Comment: Are you placing it in the same line that you intialize it for e.g. ie4 = Entry(input_frame, width=50).place(x=150, y=180)? If yes then this might be the issue here since you are not assigning the object to ie4 but the returned value of the .place function. Its rather better to first initialize it and place it in the next line.

Comment: All you need to do to answer this question is to write a small program to try it out. The example you gave doesn't use `place`.

Comment: Thank you very much @MatrixProgrammer, what you mentioned was the issue, I placed it in the same line and your solution worked like a charm..!!

Comment: I am glad I could help @ArunSundar

Comment: I have added a separate answer in the thread to make the problem and its solution clearly visible, incase someone visits the thread in the future. @ArunSundar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So eventhough my comment had solved the question just for reference for someone who may visit the thread in the future, The problem here was with the object assignment.

You had been expecting that doing something like this -:

```
ie4 = Entry(input_frame, width=50).place(x=150, y=180)
```

would assign the newly initialized entry object to the variable ie4, but its not the case as it turns out, this is because, the object you initialize is then being used in the same line to call it's inner function place.
This means that what is being stored in ie4 is not the object but the returned value of the function place that had been called on it.

Thus By first initializing in one line and calling function on it in the other seems to work, Like so -:

```
ie4 = Entry(input_frame, width=50) # Assign the obj to ie4.
ie4.place(x=150, y=180) # Call the place function on ie4 and thus on the obj.
```

Also I suggest following a similar way of initialization for all other tkinter widgets incase they are to be used longterm in your program, in this case if you just wanted to place the entry temporarily and then destroy the window it had been placed on, then it could be done in oneline, but here since you need the widget to be displayed for a major
part of your program first storing it in ie4 and then executing functions from there is a better practice.